# Find last word in a text string and wrap in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a text string, for example:

```
<div id="ideal">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy Stack Overflow user</div>
```

I'd like to wrap the **last word** ('user') in HTML to produce:

```
<div id="ideal">
     The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy 
     Stack Overflow <span class="foo">user</span>
</div>
```

So far, I've split the string using spaces and looked at replacing a match, but most solutions use a regex, but the regex could be a word that's repeated elsewhere in the string.

I've got the following working using substring at present:

```
var original = document.getElementById("ideal").textContent;

var para = original.split(" ");
var paracount = para.length;
var wordtoreplace = para[paracount-1];

var idx = original.lastIndexOf(wordtoreplace);
var newStr = original.substring(0, idx) + '<span class="foo">' + wordtoreplace + '</span>';
```

But this only works using pure javascript and not as a repeatable function across many instances of `<div class="ideal">`

Is there a repeatable way of using javascript or jQuery to do this (via class rather than id) to one or more instances of `<div class="ideal">`?

Comment: Why not making a function with that code and pass the element to target to that function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$('.ideal').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace(/(\S+)\s*$/, '<span class="foo">$1</span>'));
});
```

***[The working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/NYz33/)***

Comment: +1 I was about to post the same thing... just slightly different: http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/wCvT2/

Comment: Light and short. Love it!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to split the text, grab the last element, do your work, and rejoin the array.

```
var text = $('#ideal').text();
var arrText = text.split(' ');
var arrLength = arrText.length

arrText[arrLength-1] = '<span class="foo">' + arrText[arrLength-1] + '</span>';

$('#ideal').html(arrText.join(' '));
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/sKZCa/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can put your logic into a function, like wrapLast, and use JQuery.each to iterate all matched elements with ".ideal".

```
$(".ideal").each(function(idx, node){
    wrapLast($(node));
});
```

I put a simple example on [jsiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sKZCa/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice way if you're not opposed to extending the prototype and will use it a lot.

http://jsbin.com/esimed/1/edit

```
Element.prototype.wrapLastWord = function (left, right) {
  var words = this.innerHTML.split(' ');
  var lastWord = words[words.length - 1];
  words[words.length - 1] = left + lastWord + right;
  this.innerHTML = words.join(' ');
}
```

You could change this into another function not extending the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple, manual way to do it, there are better ways, but it works.

Steps: Split string into array, find array length and subtract 1 to get last element (b/c it starts at 0), and join it all back together again.

```
var strarr = array();
var str = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy Stack Overflow user';
strarr = str.split(' ');

// the -1 accounts for array starting at 0
var wheremylastoneat = strarr.length - 1;

// adds the class to the contents of the last element of the array
strarr[wheremylastoneat] = '<span class="foo">'+strarr[strarrlen]+'</span>';

// puts the pieces back together
str = strarr.join();
```